# How to generate faster local notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I am generating Local notification when Push notification(Actionable) are received but app is closed or in background. I have used following code to generate local notification in objective-c.

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
       // localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotification.alertBody = @"Security settings enabled, tap to start the application";
        localNotification.category = @"LOCAL_NOTIFICATION"; //  Same as category identifier
       // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];

}
```

1.When i drag notification trey down(Notification Center) not from alert it generate local notification fine in 1 sec.

2.But while press action from alert(while at home) it 
 it takes 3-4 seconds for local notification to appear.

Why there is time difference between action from alert(press action from home) and Notification center(swipe down notification trey)
generating local notification?

How to make it faster? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the presentLocalNotificationNow method instead of scheduleLocalNotification to make your notification fire instantly:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
```